# Generating a unique key-secret to identify a system

Tags: php, hash

I need to generate a unique identifier based on some information. There will be multiple clients and one server. Each client will call a web service at server for the first time registration. Each client will send system name (considered to be unique), logged in user name, date of registration, mac-address (probable) etc.

Based on this information, I want to generate a unique identifier for that particular user. My Server is written in PHP. I know some hash methods can generate some unique key, but what is the standard and what is being used generally?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

An effective approach to this is to add a salt (a few characters known only to the server) to the concatenated details from the clients. Take a [hash](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) of that data. In the example below, the salt is `mysalt`.

```
<?php
echo hash('ripemd160', 'mysalt' . clientHostname . clientUsername . clientRegistrationDate);
?>
```

This approach means that the hash can't easily be guessed/reverse-engineered by a third party.

Comment: Down-voting because he specifically said that he knows how to use hash and asked for a standard.

Comment: I think you'll find that this is idiomatic (i.e.: generally used, a standard) use of hash functions; as the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

One standard for unique identification is [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). There are 5 versions to choose from depending on what data you can supply and how obfuscated it needs to be.

If you're able to install PECL extensions, there's a very good one: http://pecl.php.net/package/uuid. If not search for PHP UUID and you'll find some pure php implementations.